# Dyanamic Programming - Coin Change Problem

Tags: algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

I am solving the following problem from hackerrank 
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/coin-change/problem

I 'm unable to solve the problem , so I have looked at the editorial and they mentioned

> T(i, m) = T(i, m-i)+T(i+1, m)

I'm unable to get big picture of why this solution works on a higher level. (like a proof in CLRS  or simple understandable example)

Solution which I have written is as follows

```
fun(m){
 //base cases
 count = 0;
 for(i..n){
  count+= fun(m-i);
 }
}
```

My solution didn't work because there are some duplicates calls. But how editorial works and what is the difference between my solution and editorial on a higher level..

Comment: Are you sure this is the formula? I think it should be `T(i, m) = T(i, m-i)+T(i  - 1, m)`...

Comment: i starts from 0 so it is i+1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in order for this to work you have to clearly define what T is. Namely, let's define T(i,m) to be the number of ways to make change for m units using only coins with index at least i (i.e. we only look at the ith coin, the (i+1)th coin, all the way to the nth coin while neglecting the first i-1 coins). Further, we define an array C such that C[i] is the value of the ith coin (note that in general C[i] is not the same as i). As a result, if there are n coins (i.e. length of C is n) and we want to make change for W units, we are looking for the value T(0, W) as our answer (make sure you can see why this is the case at this point!).

Now, we proceed by constructing a recursive definition of T(i,m). Note that our solution will either contain an additional ith coin or it won't. In the case that it does, our new target will simply be m - C[i] and the number of ways to make change for this is T(i,m - C[i]) (since our new target is now C[i] less than m). In another case, our solution doesn't contain the ith coin. In this case, we keep the target value the same, but only consider coins with index greater than i. Namely, the number of ways to make change in this case is T(i+1,m). Since these cases are disjoint and exhaustive (either you put the ith coin in the solution or you don't!), we have that

```
T(i,m) = T(i, m-C[i]) + T(i+1,m)
```

which is very similar to what you had (the C[i] difference is important). Note that if m <= 0 (since we are assuming that coin values are positive), there are 0 ways to make change. You must keep these base cases in mind when computing T(i,m).

Now it remains to compute T(0, W), which you can easily do recursively. However, you likely noticed that a lot of the subproblems are repeated making this a slow solution. The solution is to use something called dynamic programming or memoization. Namely, whenever a solution is computed, add its value to a table (e.g. T[i,m] where T is a n x W size 2D array). Then whenever you recursively compute something check the table first so you don't compute the same thing twice. This is called memoization. Dynamic programming is simple except you use a little foresight to compute things in the order in which they will be needed. For example, I would compute the base cases first i.e. the column T[ . , 0]. And then I would compute all values bordering this row and column based on the recursive definition.

Comment: Yes, it's very similar but note that you can have an unlimited number of each coin. Moreover, you are trying to reach a target number and not maximize a profit given a weight constraint.